# Remove multiple parts of a video with ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg

Here is what I am trying to do for 2 days now and I can't find anything about it. I have an mp4 file (2 minutes long) from that mp4 file I want to remove some parts, I do NOT want to cut some parts and merge them afterwards. Let me give you an example which I saw from Mike Baum's question about something similar.

Here is the video

`================================`
From this video I want to remove some part for example I want to remove from minute 1.25 to 1.80 and I want that part to just get removed NOT exported.

`================||==========||===` As you can see the part in between the two "||" should get removed and then the video's length should become 1.45 minutes because we removed 0.55 minutes so the video will become this

`===================`.

Also this thing can happen more than once per video. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

After finally using the right search word "trimming" I found what I was looking for!

```
ffmpeg -i utv.ts -filter_complex \
"[0:v]trim=duration=30[av];[0:a]atrim=duration=30[aa];\
 [0:v]trim=start=40:end=50,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[bv];\
 [0:a]atrim=start=40:end=50,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[ba];\
 [av][bv]concat[cv];[aa][ba]concat=v=0:a=1[ca];\
 [0:v]trim=start=80,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[dv];\
 [0:a]atrim=start=80,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[da];\
 [cv][dv]concat[outv];[ca][da]concat=v=0:a=1[outa]" -map [outv] -map [outa] out.ts
```

Comment: Can be simplified to `ffmpeg -i utv.ts -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=duration=30[av];[0:a]atrim=duration=30[aa];[0:v]trim=start=40:end=50,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[bv];[0:a]atrim=start=40:end=50,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[ba];[0:v]trim=start=80,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[cv];[0:a]atrim=start=80,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[ca];[av][aa][bv][ba][cv][ca]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1" out.ts`

Comment: Oh, it really got simplified! Thanks a lot cause it's like really hard for me to understand how the command works.

Comment: By the way, can you by any chance tell me why this part: ```[0:v]trim=start=80,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[cv];[0:a]atrim=start=80``` is needed when it just starts, but never ends?

Comment: Without `end` that segment will stop at the end of `utv.ts`.

Comment: Aaa, I see. Thank you!